# Position button dynamically using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT: Updated Position of Clear button after Anton's Answer**

I have multiple cards displayed that stack vertically when hovered on the card stack. The card stack has a css class `card-stack` and each card has a css class `card`. There can be N number of cards as the HTML is dynamically generated. There is a "Clear All" button that is displayed on the top-right position of the cards. It has a CSS class of `clear`.

When hovered on the `card-stack`:

1. The height of `card-stack` needs to dynamically resize to  encompass the `card` and `clear` buttons.

I am not sure how to do this using CSS, because I am not sure if there is a way to dynamically calculate the height of the `card-stack` or the `card` elements and add height to it. The CSS I am using to achieve that behavior are:

```
.card-stack:hover {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70vh; /* Calculate dynamically */
  background-color:red;
}
```

[CodePen for the above code is here](https://codepen.io/vpdevbox/pen/ZEBmpOv)

Code Snippet for the above pen is here:

```js
function remove(element) {
  element.remove();
}

function removeAllCards(element) {
  element.remove();
  document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(el => el.remove());
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e8eaed;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2vh;
  right: 2vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #00000080;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #00000040, 0 5px 5px 0#00000020;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  padding:15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.card {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * 20px) - 50%)) scale(calc(1.0 + var(--y) * 0.05));
}

.card-avatar {
  display:block;
}
.card-avatar img {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
}
.card-title {
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.card-header {
  height:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.card-body {
  margin-top:-30px;
}

.card-stack:hover .card:not(:nth-child(2)), .card-stack:hover .card:not(:last-child) {
  transform: translateY(calc((var(--y) * -105% + 200px)));
  box-shadow: none;
}

.card-stack:hover {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70vh; /* Calculate dynamically */
  background-color:red;
}

.card-stack:hover .clear {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.card-stack {
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2vh;
  right: 2vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  padding:5px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.clear {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="card-stack">
  <div class="clear"><button name="clear" value="Clear all" onclick="removeAllCards(this)">Clear All</button></div>
  <div class="card" style="--y:1" onclick="remove(this)">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-avatar">
        <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">Announcement 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      This is announcement 1.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="--y:2" onclick="remove(this)">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-avatar">
        <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">Announcement 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      This is announcement 2.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="--y:3" onclick="remove(this)">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-avatar">
        <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">Announcement 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      This is announcement 3.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="--y:4" onclick="remove(this)">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-avatar">
        <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/363633-200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">Announcement 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      This is announcement 4.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you make `.clear { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }`?
PS You will need to remove float and set height and width (maybe).

Comment: It is possible to do that, but the only caveat is the `card-stack` height will have to be dynamically adjusted based on the number of cards that stack up.

Comment: @Anton Mitsev Updated the question after incorporating your answer

Comment: If you can use class="--y:XXX", you can put the highest number in the `card-stack` element also. Then change its height (or min-height) like `min-height: calc(var(--y) * 100px + 200px);` and just play with the numbers. I hope this works for you.

Comment: all cards have same height? if yes get one card height and multiply by the number, add space for the button.. if not, loop through all cards elements and aggregate total height.. this function should be called on removeElement too

Comment: @AntonMitsev I tried setting your calculation for `.card-stack:hover {
  position: fixed;
  height: calc((var(--y) * 20vh + 20vh));
  background-color:red;
}` but it doesn't seem to work